# Keeping only a few changes from the data structure

Tags: c, arrays, reference, struct

I was not sure, about the title of the question, but here's the problem.

I have an array of structures, now I pass it by reference to a function, where in, I have a priority queue, of the same structures.

Now, I process my array, by making use of the priority queue, and in the end of the process, I will have two of the attributes(say `A` and `B`) of my structure, in array changed, while I want only one of the change(`A`) to be reflected outside the function, and I want the other(`B`) change to be restored, the way it was before passing the array. I have to do it, because for the second time when I have to process the same array, but with different parameters, I want the changes of A to remain, but B to not.

What I do right now is that, after the process, once I am out of the function, I process the entire array, and where ever I have the value changed for attribute `B` I revert it back to the initial value. Now this is obviously a O(n2) operation which is no good for me.

Can I do something to make it more efficient.

I am working with C.

Comment: Pass the array of structures by value instead of by reference. Let the DOT NET framework do the work for you.

Comment: When you say O(n2) do you mean n-squared or n-times-two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `B` is of type `bool` for example, you can create a `bool` array in the function. Use the indices of the input array (integers) in the priority queue instead of structures. Use the `bool` array to access the `B`s of the input array:

```
void func(Type *Input, size_t n) 
{
    bool B[n];
    queue<size_t> pqueue;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
       B[i] = Input[i].B;
    size_t index;
    while (index = pqueue.front()) {
       // do something with Input[index]
       // B[index] = false;
       // rest of the function
    }
}
```

Comment: basically, copy all the B attributes into another Array and use that instead of the structure, whenever required.